# Including custom typescript declaration file in library

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, type-declaration, .d.ts, typescript-declarations

I'm having some trouble figuring out how to include a custom typescript declaration file in a library i am creating. Let me give you a little context.

I am writing a library for handling resources from the healthcare platform specification FHIR (http://hl7.org/fhir/).

To that end, i have created a d.ts file specifying all the resources i use in my library to ensure typesafety.

In my ts-files i reference the d.ts file, in which i have declared the fhir resources, but once the library is bundled with webpack, and imported into another project, the declaration file containing my fhir resources cannot be found.

Here are some code snippets that might help:

fhir.d.ts

```
/** Module containing interfaces for all used FHIR resources in accordance with FHIR version 3.5.0 */
declare module 'fhir' {
  /**
   *    Any combination of upper or lower case ASCII letters ('A'..'Z', and 'a'..'z', numerals ('0'..'9'), '-' and '.', with a length limit of 64 characters. (This might be an integer, an un-prefixed OID, UUID or any other identifier pattern that meets these constraints.)
   */
  type id = string
  /**
   * A Uniform Resource Identifier Reference (RFC 3986 ). Note: URIs are case sensitive.
   */
  type uri = string
  /**
   * A URI that refers to a canonical URI.
   */
  type canonical = uri
  /**
   * A stream of bytes, base64 encoded (RFC 4648).
   */
  type base64Binary = string
  /**
   * A string which has at least one character and no leading or trailing whitespace and where there is no whitespace other than single spaces in the contents
   */
  type code = string
  /**
   * A date, or partial date (e.g. just year or year + month) as used in human communication. The format is YYYY, YYYY-MM, or YYYY-MM-DD, e.g. 2018, 1973-06, or 1905-08-23. There SHALL be no time zone.
   */
...
[shortened for brevity]
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationDir": "typings",
    "removeComments": false,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "types": ["jasmine"],
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "<project-name>",
  "version": "1.1.1",
  "description": "<project-description>",
  "main": "./dist/main.js",
  "typings": "./typings/src/main.d.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "npm run clean && webpack --mode production",
    "clean": "rimraf dist build coverage",
    "lint": "tslint --project tsconfig.json 'src/**/*.{ts,tsx}'",
    "test": "karma start"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/es6-promise": "^3.3.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.35",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.4.1",
    "karma": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-typescript": "^3.0.13",
    "prettier": "^1.14.3",
    "ts-loader": "^5.1.0",
    "tslint": "^5.11.0",
    "tslint-config-prettier": "^1.15.0",
    "tslint-config-standard": "^8.0.1",
    "typescript": "^3.0.3",
    "webpack": "^4.19.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0"
  }
}
```

Can you help me?

Comment: I'm going to need some more information.  Do I understand correctly that one of your source files has a `<reference>` directive pointing to `fhir.d.ts`?  If so, what is the path of that source file and what is the path of the declaration file that gets generated from it?  Is the `<reference>` directive present in the generated declaration file?  If so, is the path to `fhir.d.ts` correct?  Can you give an example of the source file from the other project that imports the library?

Comment: Actually - my files did not contain a triple slash directive. Adding one fixed the problem. Thank you!